# Decode a qr-code From UIimage to string

Tags: ios, qr-code

I am trying to decode a qr-code UIimage to a string but couldn't find any SDK for it.

Currently using ZBar SDK to scan qr-code from the front camera, but the SDK doesn't support Image scanning from UIimage.

Please help~

Comment: Don't use ZBar SDK to scan QR Codes in iOS7, for several reasons.  iOS7 introduced native API's for scanning barcodes (though this still doesn't deal with still images).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will try to look that up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read QR code from static image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956538/how-to-read-qr-code-from-static-image)